# Image is not capturing correctly in dropdown icon using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html2canvas

I m having following code to convert image using html2canvas. It is working fine but the select tag icon (down arrow) is not coming when capture the image

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>html2canvas</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  button{
   display:block;
   height:20px;
   margin-top:10px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  .icon-diamond:before {
    content: "\e943";
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="target">
  <div style="position:relative;" class="noteclasscontainer" >
     <span style="font-size: 60px;" class="glyphicon">&#xe022;

        <span style="color:white;font-size: 21px; position: absolute; top: 16px;left:10px;">dd</span>
     </span>
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative;" class="noteclasscontainer">
     <select>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>1</option>
     </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
 <script>
  window.takeScreenShot = function() {
      html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
          onrendered: function (canvas) {
              document.body.appendChild(canvas);
          },
          width:320,
          height:220
      });
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Image is capturing correctly but only the select icon is not coming properly.how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of browsers default CSS, everything is not accessible to html2canvas, and it should not be (possible leak of privacy info on some OS).

Maybe this exact one could be tweaked for chrome, since chrome does expose some of its [shadow selectors](https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334), but I don't even know if it is in the list, and anyway, since non-standards these selectors could change at any time in the future, and here is how it looks like on my FF :

[image: screenshot of OP's result on FF : a gray box]

So the best for you, is to create the dropdown entirely from scratch. This way all UAs will show the same, and html2canvas will be able to "snapshot" it.